# How to authenticate SharePoint Online using ClientID and secret in .net CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, sharepoint-online

I was trying to connect to a SharePoint list using a .net CORE console app. I got the error message as :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.TokenHelper' threw an exception.'
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Below is the code sample. Same works fine in .net standard version :

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using System;

namespace Share_Point_POC_Core
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
           
            string siteUrl = "https://a.b.com/sites/test";
            string clientId = "33345cb6-555a-777f-9b7b-0d3aaec2222c";
            string clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx=";

            using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
            {
                Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
                ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;
                clientContext.Load(collList);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other alternative in .net core?

Comment: Have you found any answer to this. I want to connect to SharePoint from my Azure functions which are written in .NET core and i am not able to connect to it.

Comment: @e2eDev unfortunately no